# Why can there not exist a pyramid with 29 corners?

Tags: geometry

> Why can there not exist a pyramid with 29 corners?

I tried to find a pattern, it seems like I can draw a pyramids with corners, 3,4,5, and 6. 7 becomes tricky and 29 isn’t something I even can conceptualize. Ofcourse there is probably a pattern which one on the bases of would conclude that it is an impossibility.

Thanks for your assistance in advance.

Comment: How can you draw a pyramid with $3$ vertices? As far as I know, you cannot have less corners than a tetrahedron, which has 4 vertices.

Comment: I thought of the numbers of vertices just in the base. I agree with your statement.

Answer (score 6):

Let the pyramids' base have $n$ vertices. There is also one more vertex on top, so there are in total $n+1$ vertices.

For a pyramid with $29$ vertices, the base must be a $28$-sided polygon. This might be hard to visualise because there are so many sides, but it is possible.

[image]

Comment: Added one such :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks! How did you find that image?

Comment: Being a tenured lecturer, I could afford to cough up the dough and purchase a personal license to Mathematica :-) It can be relatively easily coerced to produce such images. I first built a list of the coordinates and then defined a list of polygons forming this pyramid. Piece of cake, really.