# Why is a 29 sided (edged) pyramid not possible?

Tags: geometry

Tried to find a pattern, could not do it, any tip? It could have 3,4,5,6 edges in the base but then everything brakes down for me. Any tips?

Comment: To be clear ... In your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2914118/409), you said that you thought "vertices" only counted items in the pyramid's base. Are you thinking the same kind of thing here? Usually, "edges" counts *all* edges, both the ones along the base, and the "lateral" ones that meet the apex. If you think about *that*, you'll see that there are just as many base edges as lateral edges, which makes the total number even; then simply note that $29$ is odd..

Comment: Thanks! Got it!

Answer (score 0):

If by pyramid you mean a solid figure with a polygon as a base and then an edge for every vertex of the polygon, connecting it to a unique vertex, it is easy to see that the number of edges must be an even number.

Indeed, let $n$ be the number of edges of the base (an $n$-agon). The also the number of vertices is $n$: though, the number of edges connecting the vertices to the apex is also $n.$

In total, you have $2n$ edges in the pyramid. Being 29 an odd number, you can't have such a pyramid.